# Wordpress - mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) error on production server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm getting a warning message when I enable wordpress debug mode.

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in
>   /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/test/manage_registrations.php on
>   line 46
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/test/manage_registrations.php
>   on line 46

PHP code:

```
$extrawhere1=" order by id desc LIMIT $start, $limit";
$sqlSearch="select * from visa where 1=1 $extrawhere $extrawhere1";
$query="select * from visa where 1=1 $extrawhere order by id desc ";
$_SESSION['export_data']=$query;

$num=@mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
$select_product=mysql_query($sqlSearch);
```

I tried using

```
$select_product=$wpdb->query($sqlSearch);
```

But i'm still getting error message. This error is only appearing on production server and not on local server.

Comment: where is your mysql connection variable?

Comment: I'm using this code inside wordpress plugin so I assume that it already has database connectivity. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: try wpdb class for database queries like I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write these 2 lines at top of the file to check for any error

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

also check your config.php for db connection (correct or not)

May be load on your db has increased to the point where connections were unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database credentials. It seems like you are using an incorrect password. Or try:

```
$wpdb->query('select * from ..');
```

Another possibility is you are using a mysqli connection and and trying to execute mysql_query.

Or try:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ...", ARRAY_A);
print_r($query);
foreach($query as $row)
{
// do stuff with $row here.
}
exit;
```

Comment: After modifying the code i'm getting this error. `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer`

Comment: You are using the wpdb class not mysql functions. Check my updated answer.